# Enabling X Ray for Lambda using SDK vs Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I have Lambda Functions written in python. I want to enable log monitoring for identifying errors. Planning on enabling X Ray for the lambda functions, but I see 2 ways for enabling it. One through X Ray SDK's which will involve code changes. Other using Lambda console, using checkbox for enabling X Ray tracing directly. So, I want to know what's the difference between enabling X Ray tracing using Console and SDK. And if I enable it via Console (without any code changes), is there any disadvantages?

Comment: I'm pretty sure with AWS Lambda you have to enable it via the AWS Lambda console, or via the AWS Lambda API (which is what the console is really doing when you click that checkbox). Can you link to the X-Ray SDK code you are talking about that would enable X-Ray for a Lambda function?

Comment: I am referring to the SDK for Python mentioned in this document:  [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-tracing.html)

Comment: So, I wanted to know if I enable tracing via console without adding the SDK to lambda code. How will the trace outputs differ?